# Obtaining Image File Dimensions From URL

Tags: excel, vba, dimensions

**I have this link:**
https://s23527.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/wine_speedlights_kit_lens.jpg.optimal.jpg

**It is on Cell A2:**
[image: Before]

**I want to get on Cell B2 the dimensions of the URL of this JPG**
[image: After]

(I don't mind how to get it, it can be 1920 on cell `B2` and 1080 on cell `C2`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to make an API call to `URLDownloadToFile` to download your image. In the below example, we will download to the temp folder `C:\Temp\`.

Once your image is downloaded, you will create a new Shell object, and ultimately use the `.ExtendedProperty()` property to grab your file dimensions

After you have finished downloading your file, you can go ahead and delete the temporary file using `Kill()`.

> The below method uses **Early Binding**. You will need to set a reference to
>
> ```
> Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation
> ```
>
> By going to `Tools -> References` in the VBE menu

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
            (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
            ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
            (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
            ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub test()

    Const tmpDir$ = "C:\Temp\"
    Const tmpFile$ = "tmpPicFile.jpg"
    
    Debug.Print URLDownloadToFile(0, ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value, tmpDir & tmpFile, 0, 0)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = getFileDimensions(tmpDir, tmpFile)
    Kill tmpDir & tmpFile

End Sub

Private Function getFileDimensions(filePath$, fileName$) As String

    With New Shell32.Shell
        With .Namespace(filePath).ParseName(fileName)
            getFileDimensions = .ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")
        End With
    End With
    
End Function
```

Comment: Nice as usual and I realise I don't know enough about Namespace!

Comment: Works! although the code between #Else and #End if is in red and i got the following error: "The code in this project must ne updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute."      Since I have a64-bit system I deleted the If statement to execute only the then part of the conditional, and it worked. thank you!

Comment: I encountered one small problem when trying to run it on URL that has Hebrew in it, any workaround?

Comment: Hmm @Assaf, non-latin characters are not my specialty unfortunately. I apologize for the late response. I would recommend starting a new topic for someone who may know better than I do, just include the code that's giving you issues. Good luck!